# Logstash save value for next entry

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Is it possible to save a value that I filtered out with grok to use it as an extra field for the following entry's ?

Or

Is there maybe a Plugin that can do this for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try memorize

for example:

```
memorize {
       fields => ["PRODUCT"]
       default => { "PRODUCT" => "NOTFOUND" }
}
```

last product name will be saved at PRODUCT field,
If product name has been never found the PRODUCT field will 
be included the default value in this example "NOTFOUND"

for more information go to:
https://github.com/alcanzar/logstash-filter-memorize

You can use the advance option with ruby code, look at:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/keeping-global-variables-in-ls/39908/19